# Embedding Matplotlib in Tkinter doesn't dispay anything

Tags: animation, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to use the figure that is being created inside the class "SubplotAnimation" and place it to my graph page but it doesn't work.. Please help me... Here is my code (Tried to take all the unnecessary stuff, but some are left...):

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
#import tkinter as tk
import Tkinter as tk

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class SubplotAnimation(animation.TimedAnimation):
    def __init__(self):
        fig = plt.figure()
        fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
        ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0), colspan=2)
        ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2, 2), (1, 0), colspan=2)

        self.t = np.linspace(0, 80, 400)
        self.x = np.cos(2 * np.pi * self.t / 10.)
        self.y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * self.t / 10.)
        self.z = 10 * self.t


        ax2.set_xlabel('y')
        ax2.set_ylabel('z')
        self.line2 = Line2D([], [], color='black')

        ax2.add_line(self.line2)

        ax2.set_xlim(0, 800)
        ax2.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        ax3.set_xlabel('x')
        ax3.set_ylabel('z')
        self.line3 = Line2D([], [], color='black')

        ax3.add_line(self.line3)

        ax3.set_xlim(0, 800)
        ax3.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, interval=50, blit=True)



    def _draw_frame(self, framedata):
        i = framedata

        self.line2.set_data(self.z[:i], self.y[:i])

        self.line3.set_data(self.z[:i], self.x[:i])


        self._drawn_artists = [self.line2, self.line3]

    def new_frame_seq(self):
        return iter(range(self.t.size))

    def _init_draw(self):
        lines = [self.line2, self.line3]
        for l in lines:
            l.set_data([], [])


#ani.save('test_sub.mp4')
    @property
    def fig(self):
        return self._fig

plt.show()





class MainPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        root = tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Heeeeelp")

        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



        #********** FRAMES*******#

        self.frames = {} #empty..

        frame = GraphPage(container, self)

        self.frames[GraphPage] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(GraphPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()



class GraphPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Help")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NW')


        ani = SubplotAnimation()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ani.fig, self)

        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=3, sticky='NSEW')


app = MainPage()
app.geometry("980x640")

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, some things are needed to make this work.

First of all, I don't really understand why you have the code

```
@property
def fig(self):
    return self._fig
```

but I think you need to just delete this. Also remove the `plt.show()` beneath it since that does nothing.

Then you need to rename `fig` in `SubplotAnimation` to `self.fig`:

```
self.fig = plt.figure()
self.fig.set_size_inches(10, 7)
```

Lastly, you should take the call to `animation.TimedAnimation.__init__`, put it right behind `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(ani.fig, self)` and change it to

```
animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(ani, ani.fig, interval=50, blit=True)
```

I believe that are all the steps needed to make it work.

---

If you want to keep the initialization of the animation in your `SubplotAnimation` class, you can also make a new function to initialize it like

```
def _init_animation(self):
    animation.TimedAnimation.__init__(self, self.fig, interval=50, blit=True)
```

And call it after `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(...)` using

```
ani._init_animation()
```

Comment: btw the reason that I had the "@property" was because I had a warning for accessing to a protected member since I was calling the fig from another file..